# Can I create more "media min-width" cases for Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Boostrap 3 comes with this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Can I freely add more min-width cases? what considerations should I have?

I want to have more cases between 1200px and, say, 1920px... because in a 1920px I end up having a container of 1170px and that sucks because it could be, say, 1300px

Comment: what's wrong with just using container-fluid and be a happy camper? and if needed, just set `container-fluid: max-width:1300px` like the cool kids do

Comment: @Fabio thanks! container-fluid was all what I needed, and in my own stylesheet I added the max-width (so that it doesn't look extremely wide in wide monitors). Maybe you could post this as an answer

Comment: ok, I added it as answer with some explanation and code :)

Comment: hi i am in the same situation and i thought I could use '@media (min-width: 1920px) .container {
    width: 1890px;
}' i also use https://github.com/BenWhitehead/bootstrap-big-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you need to use different break-points for `container` class, you may face 2 scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

You know the breaking point. In this case, you can modify the SASS or LESS files, or simply create a customized version at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes

**Scenario 2:**

The breaking point is variable. In this case you use the class `.container-fluid` . This class can be (and is usually) used with `container` class in order to have some control of content inside, but the same way, you can create full screen layouts with a `.semi-container` class which is a somewhere between the `.container` class and the full width of the screen. Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid"><!-- full width -->
   <div class="semi-container container-fluid"><!-- max-width -->
      <div class="container"><!-- container -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and then the CSS for `.semi-container` would be

```
.semi-container{max-width:1300px} /* or whatever you need */
```

Comment: scenario 2 was just what I needed... I just had forgotten about the existance of container-fluid

Comment: yes I figured, but see that I added that semi-container class. That is in case that you need to have more control. For example, if you have more than one max-width container-fluid (the full-width panels width a less than full width example I gave you is quite common, but would also apply to media queries, it's just an easy trick to manage those divs :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as that. Bootstrap 3 comes with 4 classes:

1. xs (extra small) 0-768
2. sm (small) 768-992
3. md (medium) 992-1200
4. lg (large) >1200

And the container class is linked to this classes, so if you want to have other stepps between this width's you must start with adding a new class for example: xxs (extra extra small) 0-384 (witch is not implemented in bootstrap right now), you have to add this classes:

```
.col-xxs-1, .col-xxs-2, .col-xxs-3, .col-xxs-4,
.col-xxs-5, .col-xxs-6, .col-xxs-7, .col-xxs-8,
.col-xxs-9, .col-xxs-10, .col-xxs-11, .col-xxs-12 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 384px) {
    .col-xxs-1,
    .col-xxs-2,
    .col-xxs-3,
    .col-xxs-4,
    .col-xxs-5,
    .col-xxs-6,
    .col-xxs-7,
    .col-xxs-8,
    .col-xxs-9,
    .col-xxs-10,
    .col-xxs-11 {
        float: left;
    }

    .col-xxs-1 {
        width: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-2 {
        width: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-4 {
        width: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-5 {
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-7 {
        width: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-8 {
        width: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-10 {
        width: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-11 {
        width: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-1 {
        left: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-2 {
        left: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-3 {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .col-xss-push-4 {
        left: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-5 {
        left: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-6 {
        left: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-7 {
        left: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-8 {
        left: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-9 {
        left: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-10 {
       left: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-push-11 {
       left: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-1 {
        right: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-2 {
        right: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-3 {
        right: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-4 {
        right: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-5 {
        right: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-6 {
        right: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-7 {
        right: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-8 {
        right: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-9 {
        right: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-10 {
        right: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-pull-11 {
        right: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-xxs-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66666666666666%;
    }
}
```

And also the container class you wrote:

```
@media (min-width: 384px)
    .container {
        width: 372px;
    }
```

As you can see, it is very complicated, and it's recomanded not to use bootstrap if you want to customize it very very much.

Comment: while this is a GREAT answer and very informative, I don't think it's related to the question

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create more breakpoints etc. As long as you're not altering the bootstrap stylesheet it you won't affect the framework.

In reality you need to make cases for 320, 480, 600 etc... More than that.

In truth the bootstrap grid is only a starting point. I mean, come on - you can expect that everything under 768 deserves one rule.

As comprehensive as it is, bootstrap is still only supposed to be a starting point.

I've done tons of things like:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  col-xs-4 {
    width: 49.999%;
  }
}
```

Anyone who tells you you can't needs a smack - just make sure to test what you've done.

Since your example only targets .container you're pretty safe. All the percentage based widths under it should work as expected.